# Reading from ifstream won't read whitespace

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing a custom lexer in C++ and when attempting to read in whitespace, the ifstream won't read it out. I'm reading character by character using `>>`, and all the whitespace is gone. Is there any way to make the ifstream keep all the whitespace and read it out to me? I know that when reading whole strings, the read will stop at whitespace, but I was hoping that by reading character by character, I would avoid this behaviour.

Attempted: `.get()`, recommended by many answers, but it has the same effect as `std::noskipws`, that is, I get all the spaces now, but *not* the new-line character that I need to lex some constructs.

Here's the offending code (extended comments truncated)

```
while(input >> current) {
    always_next_struct val = always_next_struct(next);
    if (current == L' ' || current == L'\n' || current == L'\t' || current == L'\r') {
        continue;
    }
    if (current == L'/') {
        input >> current;
        if (current == L'/') {
            // explicitly empty while loop
            while(input.get(current) && current != L'\n');
            continue;
        }
```

I'm breaking on the `while` line and looking at every value of `current` as it comes in, and `\r` or `\n` are definitely not among them- the input just skips to the next line in the input file.

Comment: If you break on the while line then surely you would expect not to see `\n` in `current` as if `get` encountered a `\n` you'd be on the continue line and not the while line. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: `L'\n'` is 16bit `wchar_t`, not 8bit `char`, but that should be no difference.

Comment: @Charles: Then it would stop breaking and not start showing the contents of the next line on the file. @Rene: It's a `wifstream`.

Comment: Use `input.get()` for all three inputs?

Comment: @Rene: The first two are working completely as expected and there's no whitespace for them to skip.

Comment: So it might be the logic? See my edited answer.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I ended up just cracking open the Windows API and using it to read the whole file into a buffer first, and then reading that buffer character by character. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 36):

There is a manipulator to disable the whitespace skipping behavior:

```
stream >> std::noskipws;
```

Comment: I get all the spaces, but still not newlines.

Comment: And you could also use `stream.unsetf(ios_base::skipws)`; to remove that format flag manually.

Comment: @sth: That's exactly what `noskipws` does.

Answer (score 14):

The operator>> eats whitespace (space, tab, newline). Use `yourstream.get()` to read each character.

Edit:

Beware: Platforms (Windows, Un*x, Mac) differ in coding of newline. It can be '\n', '\r' or both. It also depends on how you open the file stream (text or binary).

Edit (analyzing code):

After

```
  while(input.get(current) && current != L'\n');
  continue;
```

there will be an `\n` in `current`, if not end of file is reached. After that you continue with the outmost while loop. There the first character on the next line is read into `current`. Is that not what you wanted?

I tried to reproduce your problem (using `char` and `cin` instead of `wchar_t` and `wifstream`):

```
//: get.cpp : compile, then run: get < get.cpp

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char c;

  while (std::cin.get(c))
  {
    if (c == '/') 
    { 
      char last = c; 
      if (std::cin.get(c) && c == '/')
      {
        // std::cout << "Read to EOL\n";
        while(std::cin.get(c) && c != '\n'); // this comment will be skipped
        // std::cout << "go to next line\n";
        std::cin.putback(c);
        continue;
      }
     else { std::cin.putback(c); c = last; }
    }
    std::cout << c;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This program, applied to itself, eliminates all C++ line comments in its output. The inner while loop doesn't eat up all text to the end of file. Please note the `putback(c)` statement. Without that the newline would not appear.

If it doesn't work the same for `wifstream`, it would be *very* strange except for one reason: when the opened text file is *not saved as 16bit char* and the `\n` char ends up in the wrong byte...

Comment: Don't get `\r` either, and I'm opening in text mode on Windows, which is CRLF.

Comment: @DeadMG : When I use `int c = std::cin.get();` I get ASCII 10 on a Windows machine when I hit ENTER, so it should work for `ifstream` in the same way.

Comment: That's not what happens. What happens is that the whole file gets read in the while loop and it doesn't exit. What's intended is pretty much what you said- when the end of line is found, the loop is terminated and it continues in the outer loop.

Comment: @DeadMG : That's strange... So I did another attempt.

Answer (score 6):

You could open the stream in binary mode:

```
std::wifstream stream(filename, std::ios::binary);
```

You'll lose any formatting operations provided my the stream if you do this.

The other option is to read the entire stream into a string and then process the string:

```
std::wostringstream ss;
ss << filestream.rdbuf();
```

OF course, getting the string from the ostringstream rquires an additional copy of the string, so you could consider changing this at some point to use a custom stream if you feel adventurous.
EDIT: someone else mention istreambuf_iterator, which is probably a better way of doing it than reading the whole stream into a string.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the stream (or its buffer, specifically) in a `std::streambuf_iterator`? That should ignore all formatting, and also give you a nice iterator interface.

Alternatively, a much more efficient, and fool-proof, approach might to just use the Win32 API (or Boost) to memory-map the file. Then you can traverse it using plain pointers, and you're guaranteed that nothing will be skipped or converted by the runtime.

Comment: Interesting idea. I haven't really used that particular iterator class before, I'll take a look

Comment: I've found that this iterator is pretty much the only sane way to work with IOStreams, if you want any kind of control over what you're doing and what's happening. It's still slow, of course, as you'd expect anything that combines IOStreams (slow) with per-character I/O (also slow) to be. But it works!

Answer (score 3):

You could just Wrap the stream in a ***std::streambuf_iterator*** to get data with all whitespaces and newlines like this .

```
           /*Open the stream in default mode.*/
            std::ifstream myfile("myfile.txt");

            if(myfile.good()) {
                /*Read data using streambuffer iterators.*/
    vector<char> buf((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(myfile)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

                /*str_buf holds all the data including whitespaces and newline .*/
                string str_buf(buf.begin(),buf.end());

                myfile.close();
            }
```

Comment: +1 for the use of myfile.good() - I thought that was a typo but see that good() is true when "good()=1 eof()=0 fail()=0 bad()=0" - so seems far superior to eof() checks

Comment: BTW you can also do "std::vector<char> buf(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(myfile), {});" - not sure if that is any clearer, afaik it invokes the default constructor so {} maybe gives more of a clue as to that

Answer (score 3):

By default, this **skipws flag is already set** on the ifstream object, so we must **disable it**. The ifstream object has these default flags because of std::basic_ios::init, called on every new ios_base object ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968579/what-are-the-default-format-flags-and-widths-for-double-output-in-a-stdstrin)). **Any** of the following would work:

```
in_stream.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);
in_stream >> std::noskipws; // Using the extraction operator, same as below
std::noskipws(in_stream); // Explicitly calling noskipws instead of using operator>>
```

Other flags are listed on [cpp reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/fmtflags/).

Answer (score 2):

The stream extractors behave the same and skip whitespace.

If you want to read every byte, you can use the unformatted input functions, like `stream.get(c)`.

Comment: As @CharlesBailey's answer: I still didn't get the newline character.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use `getline` ?

You will get all the whitespaces, and while you won't get the end of lines characters, you will still know where they lie :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Use getline.

```
while (getline(input,current))
{
      cout<<current<<"\n";

}
```

Comment: not a good answer ... you might have a line without '\n' at the end ... in that case you will add '\n' even tho it was not there