# A program that removes commas from numbers

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that reads numbers from a file, removes the commas, and writes the numbers to a new file.
I have managed to do most for the work, but I don't know how to add the spaces between the numbers in the new file. 
This is my program

```
 int main()
{
    ifstream numbersDs;        // input: numbers data stream
    ofstream nubersNoComma;

    projDit();  // Project details 

    // Check if the files exist.
   numbersDs.open(inFile);
   nubersNoComma.open(outFile);

   char c;

   numbersDs >> c;

    while (!numbersDs.eof())
            {
            while ((c != ',') && (!numbersDs.eof())) \\ another .eof to avoid inf loop          
                {
                cout << c ;
                nubersNoComma << c;
                numbersDs >> c;
                }

            cout << c ;
            numbersDs >> c;
        }

    nubersNoComma.close();
    numbersDs.close(); 
}
```

this is the input:

```
148,540 5345 34,456 2 1,002
```

this is the output:

```
14854053453445621002
```

Comment: `nubersNoComma << ' ';` after the inner `while`?

Comment: or a simple replace string operation to replace the `,` with ` ` ?

Comment: Most of the question's content is irrelevant. It boils down to "how do I write a space into an `std::ofstream`?", except for the fact that you only need to because your `std::istream` eats up all the whitespace in the first place.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774825/reading-from-ifstream-wont-read-whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifstream` is eating the whitespace.  Add the following:

`numbersDs >> std::noskipws;`

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you, as "Dan Hook" mentioned, you have to further consider skipping white spaces when using stringstreams, fstreams.

```
while (!numbersDs.eof())
        {
        while ((c != ',') && (!numbersDs.eof()))
            {
            cout << c ;
            nubersNoComma << c;
             numbersDs>>std::noskipws >> c;
            }
            nubersNoComma << " ";

        cout << c ;
        numbersDs >> c;
    }
```

Comment: This code replaces commas with spaces, which is not what was asked for.

Comment: Ah i see... i thought he wants to replace, but he wants actually to seperate every char by a space?

Comment: Admittedly it's not that clear since he does not provide desired output. However, it can be deduced well enough from the question text I think (also, a bit of common sense! :D).