# How to redirect input stream to output stream in one line?

Tags: c++, linux

I want to do this:

```
cout<< cin;
```

Instead of this:

```
int x;
cin>>x;
cout<<x;
```

I have tried this:

```
cout<< (cin>>); //no luck
```

I hope it's clear that what i want.

Answer (score 7):

Or a sexy method, for a change:

```
std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you [turn off skipping of whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6774866/335858), you should be able to do it in one string, but it's going to be a pretty long string:

```
std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin)
,   std::istream_iterator<char>()
,   std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout,"")
);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/TmzdTQ)

Answer (score 2):

One byte at a time: `std::cout.put(std::cin.get());`