# Printing exactly same as input

Tags: c++

This is my answer for a question at Baekjoon.
The question was to write a program that prints exactly same as input. The input can be as big as 100 lines and each line contains at most 100 characters(numbers , alphabet, space). No line starts or ends with a space.

**example input)**

```
Hello
nice too meet
ya
```

**example output)**

```
Hello
nice too meet
ya
```

Below is my code for the question. I've tested all the cases that could happen within my knowledge except 100 lines of 100 characters. It worked for me. But it keeps failing the test. Can anyone please find what the cause is?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* line[100];
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; cin.getline((line[i]= new char), 100); i++,count++) {
        if (cin.eof()) break;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<count;i++){
        cout << line[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(line[i]= new char)` is almost certainly wrong. Use a `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look it up.

Comment: For the first year or two of learning C++, forget you ever heard of `new`.

Comment: Why would you even be buffering? Just read the line and print it directly

Comment: @JVApen - I think he wants not to mix up input-echos and output in the console window.

Comment: @JiveDadson: Yes, I don't want to mix them. I need to get all the inputs then print it all out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect input stream to output stream in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346320/how-to-redirect-input-stream-to-output-stream-in-one-line)

Comment: @fab - None of the answers there do what the OP wants.  He wants to buffer it to EOF (typically crl-Z) and then write the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn the standard library. C++ is all about not re-inventing wheels. There's a buffer called std::ostringstream that will do it all, without all those assumptions about the input.  Plus, it will be highly optimized for streaming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main() {
    std::ostringstream buffer{};
    buffer << std::cin.rdbuf();
    std::cout << buffer.str();
    return 0;
}
```

... or (less efficiently), you could use a string as your buffer. Lot's of ways to do this.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string buffer{};
    {  char ch;
       while (std::cin.get(ch)) buffer.push_back(ch);
    }
    std::cout << buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems I got tons to learn just about stream itself.