# My output file does not read the spaces from my input file

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting my program to read the spaces in my input file, I am new to  and objects in general so any help would be appreciated.

My input file is: Hello my name is Pierre. I   like   to   code   .
My output file is: HellomynameisPierre.Iliketocode.

Another question I have is how can I check if my string has more than one space, and if it does, replace it with only one space.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void clean_file(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout);

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    clean_file(fin, fout);
}

void clean_file(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout)
{
    fin.open("string.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "File could not open.";
        exit(1);
    }
    fout.open("cleanString.txt");
    if (fout.fail())
    {
        cout << "File could not open.";
        exit(1);
    }
    char line;
    while (fin >> line)
    {
        fout << line;
    }


    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

Edit: I changed the (fin >> line) to (fin.get(line)) and it works now. Thank you.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void clean_file(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout);

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    clean_file(fin, fout);
}

void clean_file(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout)
{
    fin.open("string.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "File could not open.";
        exit(1);
    }
    fout.open("cleanString.txt");
    if (fout.fail())
    {
        cout << "File could not open.";
        exit(1);
    }
    char line;
    while (fin.get(line))
    {
        fout << line;
    }


    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite similar to this one:

[Reading from ifstream won't read whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774825/reading-from-ifstream-wont-read-whitespace)

Instead of using `(fin >> line)`, try using the `get()` function:

```
(fin.get(line))
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, that did help my problem. I changed my (fin >> line) to (fin.get(line)) but now I am trying to figure out how to read certain characters like extra spaces and to insert one space instead of it.

Comment: You could do something where you compared `line` to `32` (32 is the ASCII number for a space). Something along the lines of this might work: `//32 is the ASCII value for a space.
   if(line == 32)
    {
        cout << line;
        if(fin.get(line != NULL))
        {
            if(line == 32)
            {
                //Do not print this since it will be the second whitespace in a row.
                
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Good point. I wasn't sure if I should have included more content or just send the link. Thanks!

Comment: @Tman:  Go ahead and edit your answer to include the missing information.  If you don't your answer will probably be removed soon as a link-only answer.  You can read the Help pages to learn why link-only answers are considered bad.