# Clear any extra spaces in a string by only using the <iostream>, <fstream> and <cstdlib>

Tags: c++

[This is a link to my previous question with some code that I have.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338799/my-output-file-does-not-read-the-spaces-from-my-input-file)

Thanks.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void clean_file(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout);

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    clean_file(fin, fout);
}

void clean_file(ifstream& fin, ofstream& fout)
{
    fin.open("string.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "File could not open.";
        exit(1);
    }
    fout.open("cleanString.txt");
    if (fout.fail())
    {
        cout << "File could not open.";
        exit(1);
    }
    char line;
    while (fin.get(line))
    {
        fout << line;
    }


    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

The input file I currently have has extra spaces between some of the words and I want to figure out how to check if the string has more than one space and if it does, to replace it with one space. I am thinking I have to check each character by itself and if the consecutive characters are both spaces then I need to replace it with only one. I have searched my question online but I can't find out how to do it by only using the libraries I mentioned before.

Comment: You should make your question standalone, especially when the other question is a duplicate.  Please add the relevant details and explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I was on my phone when I posted this. I just posted the code I have with some more details on what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Keep track of the last character read, initialize it to a space before the loop.  If the last it is a space and the current is a space, don't write it to the output.  There are better, and likely faster, ways to do this without the arbitrary restrictions.

Comment: Okay, I will try to figure how to do that. The reason that I can only use those 3 libraries is because we are using those libraries for this section in my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the stream word by word and write the words separated by one space (the downside is that it will remove all line breaks too):

```
void clean_stream(std::istream& fin, std::ostream& fout) {
    std::string word;
    bool first = true;
    while (fin >> word) {
        if (!first)
            fout << ' ';
        fout << word;
        first = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much, that worked. That opened my mind to the possibility of checking the end of each word instead of each character. Thank you!