# Is there a way to read spaces from a file without using std::getline?

Tags: c++, string, char, std, getline

I understand std::getline is the most efficient way of accomplishing this, is there another way that doesn't involve this?

the contents of any given file should be read in a char array

i.e. char contents[50];

Currently, if I read "He jumped over the brown fox." from a file using the standard ifstream procedure I get "Hejumpedoverthebrownfox." But I want the spaces (" ") to register as chars within the array. Is there any way to do this without std::getline?

I intend to use isalpha and isdigit on them afterwards.

Thank you

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `std::getline`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Reading from ifstream won't read whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6774825/643383)

Answer (score 1):

Use `file.get()` to read the characters one at a time (including spaces and everything else) and put them in your array.