# outputting binary data is missing some bytes

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

I have the following code

```
fin.close();
open = inName + ".xxx";
fin.open(open.c_str(),ios::binary);
fin>>noskipws;

while (fin>>_4byte[0])
{
    fout<<_4byte[0];
}
```

I also have fout open in binary mode too.
However, this code was working perfectly, but suddenly after adding a loop before it it stopped outputting all the data, it is missing somewhere around 33~55 bytes. 
I tried removing every other `fin.open` and `fin.close` to keep this one, but I keep on getting the same issue which is the output file is missing some data.

`_4byte` is an `unsigned char array`.

Comment: Are you intentionally reading into the same `unsigned char` each time, or did you mean to read in to `_4byte[1]`, etc.?

Comment: Consider providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For binary data, I'd really recommend using read() instead of the `>>` operator. Here is another post discussing various options. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774825/reading-from-ifstream-wont-read-whitespace

Comment: @AndyG _4byte[0] serves as one unsigned char.

Comment: How does the code look after the loop is added?

Comment: @Shooter Exactly, that was the issue. There was an istream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it, the issue was that I only had to add `fin.close()` after the while loop. I'm not sure why it happened. Can someone explain the reason?

Edit:
Okay that was not the issue.
After this code I had a `cin`, it actually stops writing when it reaches the cin if it hadn't done writing yet.