# What are the default Format Flags (and widths) for double output in a std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, std, precision, stringstream

What is the default format, when I'm writting a double to a `stringstream`?

```
double v = 3.0;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << v;
```

Where can I find a list of the default format setup for a `stringstream`? Is the default format the same for all derived classes of `std::istream` (within the stdlib)?

Comment: Quoting https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision "The default precision, as established by std::basic_ios::init, is 6.". I'm sure you can find the other defaults you are interested in with a little digging through the site.

Comment: Also can use a simple program to check the precision: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/365269145e1c1378

Comment: @leiyc While that gives you an answer it is by no means the answer.  If it was implantation defined then you could get any result and you wouldn't know if that was truly "correct"

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, I just take it as an example to verify the answer posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The defaults are setup by [`std::basic_ios::init`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init) and are the same for all streams derived from `ios_base`.  The defaults are:

```
rdbuf()         sb
tie()           0
rdstate()       goodbit if sb is not a null pointer, otherwise badbit.
exceptions()    goodbit
flags()         skipws | dec
width()         0
precision()     6
fill()          widen(’ ’)
getloc()        a copy of the value returned by locale()
iarray          a null pointer
parray          a null pointer
```

So the default precision is 6

Comment: you manually created this list? or is the some trick to get it?

Comment: @user463035818 Follow the [std::basic_ios::init](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init) link. It's right there on cppreference.com

Comment: @user463035818 I copied it from the standard and just added tabs to get the second column to line up.  IIRC there is a user script out there to build tables.  The DB people use it.

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find a list of the default format setup for a stringstream?

The authoritative source for all standard library behaviour is the standard document. In this case, the table labeled `basic_ios::init() effects` in the section [basic.ios.members].

```
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|   Element    |                         Value                          |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| rdbuf()      | sb                                                     |
| tie()        | 0                                                      |
| rdstate()    | goodbit if sb is not a null pointer, otherwise badbit. |
| exceptions() | goodbit                                                |
| flags()      | skipws | dec                                           |
| width()      | 0                                                      |
| precision()  | 6                                                      |
| fill()       | widen(’ ’)                                             |
| getloc()     | a copy of the value returned by locale()               |
| iarray       | a null pointer                                         |
| parray       | a null pointer                                         |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Formatting floating point numbers depends on the `floatfield` flag, which is unset in the default `flags()`. The behaviour is defined in the table `Floating-point conversions` in section [facet.num.put.virtuals].

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|                                State                                 | stdioequivalent |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| floatfield == ios_base::fixed                                        | %f              |
| floatfield == ios_base::scientific && !uppercase                     | %e              |
| floatfield == ios_base::scientific                                   | %E              |
| floatfield == (ios_base::fixed | ios_base::scientific) && !uppercase | %a              |
| floatfield == (ios_base::fixed | ios_base::scientific)               | %A              |
| !uppercase                                                           | %g              |
| otherwise                                                            | %G              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

So, formatting in the initial state should match stdio format flag `%G`. The stdio format flags are specified in the C standard in the section [Formatted input/output functions]:

> f,F
>
> A **double** argument representing a floating-point number is converted to decimal notation in style [−]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is zero and the **#** flag is not specified, no decimal-point character appears. If a decimal-point character appears, at least one digit appears before it. The value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits.
>
> e,E
>
> A **double** argument representing a floating-point number is converted in the style [-]d.ddde±dd, where there is one digit (which is nonzero if the argument is nonzero) before the decimal-point character and the number of digits after it is equal to the precision; if the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is zero and the **#** flag is not specified, no decimal-point character appears. The value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits. The **E** conversion specifier produces a number with **E** instead of **e** introducing the exponent. The exponent always contains at least two digits, and only as many more digits as necessary to represent the exponent. If the value is zero, the exponent is zero.
>
> A **double** argument representing an infinity is converted in one of the styles **[-]inf** or **[-]infinity** - which style is implementation-defined. A double argument representing a NaN is converted in one of the styles **[-]nan* or **[-nan]**(n-char-sequence) - which style, and the meaning of any n-char-sequence, is implementation-defined. The F conversion specifier produces **INF**,**INFINITY**, or **NAN** instead of **inf**,**infinity** ,or **nan**, respectively.
>
> g,G
>
> A **double** argument representing a floating-point number is converted in style **f** or **e** (or in style **F** or **E** in the case of **G** conversion specifier), depending on the value converted and the precision. Let `P` equal the precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is omitted, or 1 if the precision is zero. Then, if a conversion with style **E** would have an exponent of `X`:
>
> - if `P > X ≥ -4`, the conversion is with style **f** (or **F**) and precision `P - (X + 1)`.
> - otherwise, the conversion is with style **e** (or **E**) and precision `P - 1`.

---

> Is the default format the same for all derived classes of std::istream (within the stdlib)?

Yes, the defaults are the same.