# File reading with noskipws?

Tags: c++, file-handling

Is my approach correct to read `.txt` file including white spaces and newline (\n)?
My instructions to write the program requires me to detect spaces and newline as well so that they can be manipulated.

```
char word_from_file;
ifstream input_file;
input_file.open (*recieved_file_name+".txt");
if (input_file.good() && input_file.is_open())
{
    while (!input_file.eof())
    {
        input_file >> noskipws >> word_from_file;
        if (*recieved_choice==1)
        {
            cout << *recieved_key;
            encrypt (recieved_file_name, &word_from_file, recieved_key);
        }
    }
    input_file.close();
}
```

Comment: What is noskipws ?

Comment: @Mr.Strings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774825/reading-from-ifstream-wont-read-whitespace

Comment: More suitable for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is your program task? What does your file look like? Are you actually experiencing a problem with this code?

Comment: The program task is to encrypt `.txt` contents with shift cipher. So keeping track of spaces and newline is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct in that it reads whitespace and newlines but the error checking for the input is incorrectly positioned and this can be shortened with the use of `istream::get()`.

```
char word_from_file;
while (input_file.get(word_from_file)) {
  if (*recieved_choice == 1) {
    cout << *recieved_key;
    encrypt (recieved_file_name, &word_from_file, recieved_key);
  }
}
```

`istream::get()` reads an unformatted character from the stream, so it will automatically read whitespace and newlines.

There's also no need to check if the file opened or to manually close it. The file will close automatically at the end of the scope in which its created, and any attempted input operation is a no-op if the file didn't open.

Comment: So `while (input_file.get(word_from_file))` is reading from file? What is being passed to `encrypt (recieved_file_name, &word_from_file, recieved_key);` ?

Comment: @Ahmn21 `get()` will read from the file and enter the character into `word_from_file`. Then you call `encrypt` while passing this variable. It does the same thing as your original code only a bit shorter.